# Structures with suffix 出

Tags: grammar

According to jisho, 出 can be used as a suffix after the masu stem of a verb with meaning "amount (comprising something); amount of time or effort required to do something​".

Jisho says 出 is used in structures like 〜出がある or 〜出がない, which meaning I interpret as having to do something a lot, even though I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct or not as I have barely seen sentences with those structures. **Could you please confirm it?**

Besides, I would like to know if these two are the only ones that can be constructed or there are other structures used commonly as well with 出 as a suffix after the masu stem of a verb. If so, **could you please tell me the other most common constructions as well as their meaning and an example?**

Answer (score 2):

`[V ます-stem]-出がある` means doing the act of the verb is challenging because it requires you to deal with a large amount of something but is at the same time satisfying. For example, you might describe a long novel you consider to be worth a read as 読み出がある.

However, this construction is not so commonly used any longer. If I heard it from a young person, I would probably assume that person is speaking some dialect. Most people would say `[V ます-stem]-ごたえがある` for a similar meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining me the meaning of 〜出がある. Then 〜出がない would refer to something that is both long and unsatisfying, right? Would reading a long and tedious novel be 読み出がない?

Comment: Apart from 〜出がある and 〜出がない, are there other structures with 出 as a suffix after the masu stem of a verb?

Comment: @kanachan -  I would understand 読み出がない as meaning the volume is not enough and therefore unsatisfying rather than long and unsatisfying. If you want to say something is not worth a long read, you might say 読み甲斐がない. In any case, 〜出がある and 〜出がない are not very commonly used now and I cannot think of any other construct that consists of the ます-stem of a verb followed by 出.

Comment: "For example, you might describe a long novel you consider to be worth a read as 読み出がある." - Literally, you "get something out of" reading it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - It's more like you enjoy the process of reading it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - I mean I’ve never tried to understand it literally and don’t know where this 出 came from. But I don’t particularly get the imagery of “getting something out.”